# Programmatically redef functions

Tags: clojure

I'm currently in the start of making a tool that should modify all the functions in another namespace, and the run the "main" function in that (other) namespace. Almost like mocking in unit-testing, but for another purpose. The first step to this is to redefine functions from another namespace. The first listing shows code that works, where I explicitly name the function to be replaced.

```
(ns one)
(defn a-fun []
  (println "original"))

(defn caller []
  (a-fun))

(ns two)

(with-redefs [one/a-fun #(println "replaced")]
  (one/caller))
;; replaced
;; nil
```

The next step is getting the functions programmatically from the other namespace. This is where I have run into a wall. I've experimented much with `ns-publics`, but so far no luck. So I try to break the problem down. And the problem is that the replacement of the function is not working. The output should print "replaced" not "original".

```
(ns two)
(def target (ns-resolve 'one (symbol "a-fun")))
(def caller (ns-resolve 'one (symbol "caller")))
(with-redefs [target #(println "replaced")]
  (caller))
;; original
;; nil
```

Now, the `#'two/target` shows `#'one/a-fun` when I evaluate it in the repl. I can call `one/a-fun` by entering `((ns-resolve 'one (symbol "a-fun")))` in the repl, so I don't understand what part is not working.

I've been through a lot of documentation today, and I'm not really getting any closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [`with-redefs-fn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs-fn) like so:

```clj
(defn p [] "old")

(with-redefs-fn
  {(ns-resolve *ns* 'p) #(println "new")}
  (fn []
    (p)))
;; => new
```

This does mean that the body of `with-redefs-fn` must be a function that uses your redefined Vars.

Comment: This worked. I'm still mystified why though. The docs for ```with-redefs``` and ```with-redefs-fn``` look so similar I'm unable to reason out what made the difference.

Comment: @user55924 `with-redefs` is a macro, so it redefines literally the vars that appear in the binding form (in this case, `target`). You don't notice it working because `target` isn't the var through which the function will be called.